# How do I and Can I switch between windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 at random?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch between Ubuntu and Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83487/switch-between-ubuntu-and-windows-7)

How do I and Can I switch between windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 at random?   I have downloaded Ubuntu and WUBI.  I am very new at this and just want to make sure I don't lose my windows OS setup.  can I just boot from a disc whenever I want to use Ubuntu?  I don't want to start the WUBI process and then not be able to get back to Windows when I want and vice versa.

Comment: will I be able to switch OSs at every time I reboot computer?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot randomly switch between the OSs. It is completely deterministic. Every time you boot, you will be given a choice between Windows, and Ubuntu. If you do not do any thing the default OS (Ubuntu, in dual boot, probably Windows in WUBI) will boot after the timeout.

Hope this helps.