# Can I install Windows on Drive C and Ubuntu on drive E?

Tags: kubuntu, windows

I am a newbie trying to learn Ubuntu.  My drive C is almost full, and I read somewhere on the web that I need to remove Drive C then install Ubuntu on the empty Drive E. Then reinstall drive C. So basically, I am installing Ubuntu separately from Windows. Drive C and Drive E each is its own separate physical drive. I did not install Ubuntu from Windows.  In the BIOS boot sequence, I have Windows to boot up first, then Ubuntu second. My questions: after Windows starts up, I want to work in Ubuntu, how can I switch off Windows and start Ubuntu on Drive E? And how do I switch back to Windows from Ubuntu. Thank you so much in advance for your advice and teaching.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to install Ubuntu inside Windows using WSL or some virtual setup. Or if you want to install Ubuntu separately from Windows. It also not clear if drive E is a partition within a single physical drive that includes drive C or if it is a separate physical drive. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1457115/edit) and add all these details in your question. Otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you,  due to my limited knowledge, the question is not clear. Let me edit my question.

Comment: I think I found the answer that it cannot be done from these writings:https://askubuntu.com/questions/59943/how-to-switch-between-ubuntu-and-windows-7-without-a-reboot

Comment: Also see [Dual Booting win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on two separate physical ssds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds). Note Windows 11 may not boot if you disable secure boot in UEFI.

Comment: I am grateful for your taking the time to help me!